# How to make divs the same height as the tallest if elements are not in a container tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a loop (in wordpress) grabbing the thumbnails, titles and excerpts from the most recent posts and displaying them on the homepage in a column format. I want to make the div that contains title of each post the same height as the tallest title.

I found CSS can work if you can put all the elements in a container div but I don't know how to go about doing that.

any help would be much appreciated!

(EDIT)

ok this is what I am working with

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-6 postbox">

     <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 500, true ); //resize & crop the image
     ?>

     <?php if($image) : ?>
        <div class="hthumb">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
        </div>

     <?php endif; ?>

     <div class="art_header"> 
     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
     </div>

     <div class="hometa"> <?php web2feel_posted_on(); ?> </div>

      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
     </div>
```

this is the section that I need to be the same height. But it need to be responsive to the length of the post titles.

```
<div class="art_header"> 
     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
     </div>
```

I'm a bit rusty with Wordpress so forgive me if I haven't given all the info!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck so we can assess the problem at hand.

Comment: This isn't a WordPress question. It's CSS, and probably JavaScript. Ordinarily you'd need to run a script to measure the tallest element, then set them all to match.

Comment: What CSS are you using? What do the hthumb, art_header and the hometa classes do?